# NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate with a custom view, predicateWithSubpredicates not being called

Tags: swift, macos, nspredicateeditor

In my app I need to be able to filter items by colours.

I've subclassed the NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate and added custom view :

[image]

*Custom view is NSView with 7 NSButtons

My problem is that *predicateWithSubpredicates:* gets called only when I add/remove some rows in NSPredicateEditor.

But I want it to be called every time I choose color (clicking corresponding NSButton)

The only way I see is to copy target and action of NSTextField in *templateViews*.
Are there any other ways ?

Thanks in advance